# metaClass.'static' not working when replacing method

Tags: groovy

I'm using groovy 1.7.8.

I have the following code:

```
public class StaticClass {
    public static String getStaticString(String string) {
        return "NOT WORKING"
    }
}
```

My test:

```
void testStaticMethod() {
    StaticClass.metaClass.'static'.getStaticString = { i ->
        "WORKING"
    }

    assert "WORKING" == StaticClass.getStaticString('test')
}
```

I can not get my test to pass.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28):

Try typing the closure:

```
StaticClass.metaClass.'static'.getStaticString = { String i ->
    "WORKING"
}
```

You need to match the method signature exactly if you're trying to override something.