# Cannot replace static method

Tags: groovy, metaclass

I'm trying to replace a static method at runtime using `MetaClass`.

```
class MyClass {
    private static String getString() {
        'Hello'
    }

    String testString

    MyClass() {
        testString = getString()
    }
}

MyClass.metaClass.static.getString = { ->
    'Hello world!'
}

def test = new MyClass()
assert test.testString == 'Hello world!'
```

However this it doesn't work.

```
Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert test.testString == 'Hello world!'
       |    |          |
       |    Hello      false
       MyClass@5876a9af
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [metaClass.'static' not working when replacing method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222278/metaclass-static-not-working-when-replacing-method)

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222278/metaclass-static-not-working-when-replacing-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938551/overriding-private-method-with-metaclass-in-groovy

Two things: 1. you need to match the exact signature of the method to be replaced, 2. Depending on your Groovy version, it might be not possible to replace a private method.

Comment: @CptBartender 1. I'm already matching the exact signature (no arguments); 2. I'm using latest version 2.4.6.

Comment: @CptBartender About private method, visibility doesn't matter, it doesn't work no matter what visibility I set.

Comment: @CptBartender I would swear I tried with public visibility. I tried again, and now it works. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a [bug in Groovy 2.4.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7368), it is not possible to change private methods via metaclass. I've changed the method to public (well, default) and also changed the constructor so that it explicitly calls it's class' `getString` method and now it seems to be working in [Groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)

Full code after edits:

```
class MyClass {
    static String getString() {
        'Hello'
    }
    String testString
    MyClass() {
        testString = MyClass.getString()
    }
}
MyClass.metaClass.static.getString = {'Hello world!'}
def test = new MyClass()
assert test.testString == 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: How come that `testString = getString()` does not return the same as `testString = MyClass.getString()`? Do you know why this behavior?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. My guess is, `getString()` is calling the method directly, while `MyClass.getString()` is calling it via the same mechanism that provides metaclass extensions (It's not as "direct" in Groovy as it is in Java). IIRC I once did a test where I couldn't use metaclass extensions from Java classes. That said, it is too low-level question for my knowledge of the languages, and I wouldn't rely on this answer too much.

Comment: In fact I found the behavior of this to be even stranger. I posted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501291/replaced-static-method-not-replaced-only-when-called-from-constructor) about this. I highly suspect this is a bug in Groovy.